# ggplot2 use running variable to set geom_text label

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two datsets in my diagram, "y1" and "baseline". As labels in a ggplot diagram, I want to use the difference of the y-value of  both. I want to facilitate this on the fly.

Dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(c(10,20,40),c(0.1,0.2,0.3),c(0.05,0.1,0.2))
names(df)[1] <- "classes"
names(df)[2] <- "y1"
names(df)[3] <- "baseline"
df$classes <- factor(df$classes,levels=c(10,20,40), labels=c("10m","20m","40m"))
dfm=melt(df)
```

To start with, I defined a function which returns the y-value of the baseline corresponding to a particular x-value:

Tested it, works fine:

```
getBaselineY <- function(xValue){
  return(dfm[dfm$classes==xValue & dfm$variable=="baseline",]$value[1])
}
```

Unfortunately, parsing this function into the ggplot code only gives me the baseline y-value for the first x-value:

```
diagram <- ggplot(dfm, aes(x=classes, y=value, group=variable, colour=variable))
diagram <- diagram + geom_point() + geom_line()
diagram <- diagram + geom_text(aes(label=getBaselineY(classes)))
diagram <- diagram + theme_bw(base_size=16)
diagram
```

Nevertheless, subsetting the function call by just the x-value gives me the respective x-value for each ggplot-iteration:

```
diagram <- diagram + geom_text(aes(label=classes))
```

I don't understand how this come and how to solve it the best way. Any help is highly appreciated!

**Alternatively**, this could be solved by calculating the difference beforehand and adding an additional column to the data frame:

```
df$Difference<-df$y1-df$baseline
dfm=melt(df,id.var=c(1,4))
```

And use it directly as geom_text label:

```
diagram <- diagram + geom_text(aes(label=Difference))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your function `getBaselineY`. I guess you wrote and tested it with a single `xValue` in mind. But you are passing a vector to the function and return only the first value.

To get the labels the way you described use an `ifelse`:

```
diagram + geom_text(aes(label = ifelse(variable == "baseline", value, 
      value - value[variable == "baseline"])))
```

[image]

Comment: That solves it, thank you very much. I didn't know that value is a vector, but assumed that the function in called multiple times in some sort of iteration. I only need the difference between both, so no ifelse is needed.